# Managing Plutus accounting system for multiple model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, accounting

I am trying to create a school management system. Here there are two namespaces:School and Teacher. I am able to maintain the plutus accounting system for Teacher. Now I also need to maintain same for School as well. Following is my current configurations:

initializers/plutus.rb

```
Plutus.config do |config|
  config.enable_tenancy = true
  config.tenant_class = "School"
end
```

models/teacher.rb

```
has_many :accounts, class_name: "Plutus::Account", foreign_key: "tenant_id"
after_create :create_plutus_accounts
before_destroy :destroy_plutus_accounts
  def create_plutus_accounts
    Plutus::Asset.create(name: "Accounts Receivable", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Asset.create(name: "Cash", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Asset.create(name: "Sales Tax Paid", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Revenue.create(:name => "Sales Revenue", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Expense.create(name: "Workwear", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Expense.create(name: "Travel", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Expense.create(name: "Phone and Internet", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Expense.create(name: "Professional Development", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Expense.create(name: "Professional Literature", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Expense.create(name: "Administration Costs", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Expense.create(name: "Phone and Internet", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Expense.create(name: "Office Supplies", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Expense.create(name: "Maintenance", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Expense.create(name: "Representation", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Expense.create(name: "Other General Costs", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Liability.create(name: "Unearned Revenue", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Liability.create(name: "Sales Tax Payable", tenant: self)
    Plutus::Equity.create(name: "Equity", tenant: self)
  end

  def destroy_plutus_accounts
    Plutus::Account.where(tenant: self).destroy_all
  end
```

I tried to copy paste the same code of teacher model in school model. After that when I run the  `School.first.create_plutus_accounts` I face following issue:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Teacher(#70257249141660) expected, got School(#70257261264760)
```

Comment: what is the problem

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I have added the error i am facing. Please have a look at it.